# Get message body update notification while composing email for Outlook

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I'm working on an Outlook AddIn I need to get the body of the message while user composing the mail. I know we can use **JavaScript API for Office** get body async call to fetch the body. But for long messages or messages with embedded images, it hangs Outlook for a few seconds and block user from typing. Is there any other way to get the complete message body or just the text update event without blocking user.

Applications like Grammarly seem to get live text update notifications, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature: body update notification, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins